# Select inputs not responding in Android mobile browser

Tags: android, forms, web

I have a simple form with one select input type that works fine on all desktop browsers as well as mobile Safari. However, on both my Android devices (Samsung Droid and Prevail), the select input will not respond. I'm expecting it to spawn a picker. Has anyone had a similar experience? Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code, preferably as a working example on jsfiddle.

Comment: There's no JavaScript involved. The HTML is pretty simple: `<select id="quantity" name="quantity" class="quantity">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option></select>`

Comment: Also, the Android versions for the phones are 2.2.1 and 2.2.2

Comment: Perhaps those browsers don't show the picker when there's only one option?  There's nothing the picker could do in that case.  I'm guessing there's more to it than this, or you wouldn't care that the picker doesn't get shown...?

Comment: Well, I just included one option in the above example to keep it short. There are actually 32 options. I tried using CSS to fatten up the select input for a bigger target but had no success. I'm thinking there must be an overlapping element that's stealing the event?

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered the same issue.

I'm using Bootstrap and one of the `<div>`'s in the lower section had `col-sm-12`, but no rule for `xs`. This was causing it to invisibly cover up all of the above form input elements in mobile. Switching `col-sm-12` to `col-xs-12` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes;" />
```

And I noticed that, in my case, when a parent element was hidden (and displayed again) the **select** element behaves 'disabled'. There is a bug in android =< 2.2 when you change the style, the dom is not re-rendered. You can force to re-render the dom by adding (or changing) a 'fake' attribute to force dom re-rendering. e.g:

```
myPreviousHiddenEl.setAttribute('forceRePaint','yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and I think it had something to do with overlapping like you said. To fix it I added the following CSS to the  tag like this:

```
<select style="position:relative">
```

That got the job done. :)